# Is it unethical to apply to/attend a PhD program knowing you MIGHT end up leaving it under a particular circumstance?

Tags: ethics

Hypothetically, suppose one applies to and is admitted to both **a funded PhD program in Field A and a master's program in Field B** at the same university, in different departments. Suppose there was a structure in place at the university for both programs to be undertaken concurrently (an implication of this is that I would not have to pay tuition for the normally unfunded master's program).

Is it unethical to attend both programs, knowing that depending on how the Field B master's goes, I may end up leaving the Field A PhD (after receiving my Field A master's) for the Field B PhD at the same university? Note that **this is not my intention going in**, but simply the one unlikely but possible situation in which I know that I would leave. I don't expect this is likely to happen - and if for whatever reason I don't want to or can't make the switch to the Field B PhD program at that university, I would see the Field A PhD through no matter what.

Furthermore, if it is unethical to attend both programs, is it also unethical to apply to both programs? It goes without saying that I would not misrepresent myself in my statements of purpose to either program (or to my letter writers).

Comment: Since it is unlikely that the university would let you register in both departments, I doubt you would end up in such a situation.

Comment: The university in question has a joint program that allows graduate registration in two departments, but not an interdisciplinary program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not unethical to apply to both programs.

However, for most advanced degree programs, the possibility of doing multiple programs simultaneously is remote, unless the departments have already established a method for undertaking work between the disciplines. For instance, there may be an interdisciplinary program or a "joint degree" program. In such cases, though, you will find it very difficult to find a funded program that will pay for your studies to complete a degree in another department.

Answer (score 0):

There are many "unlikely but possible" reasons you might leave a PhD halfway through. A family member might fall sick and need constant care, you might fall sick and be unable to complete, you might win the lottery, you might have a child, you might be offered an amazing opportunity in industry, your advisor might turn out to be insufferable, ... You never know what will happen, and it's a risk that everyone, including your funding source, has to accept.

There is nothing unethical to doing what's best for you if such a situation comes along, as long as you do not go in with the intention of leaving halfway through.